# Consume Json URL with JQuery returning [object object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, url

I'm trying to consume a local URL with JQuery, but it's only coming back
[object object]. Could you please help me.

Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $.getJSON(http: "//localhost:8082/pessoa/ellem", function(result) {
      $.each(result, function(i, field) {
        $("p").append(field + " ");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button> JSON </button>
```

I tested it with another link, example: https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http://vimeo.com/13211055, 
and it works normal, I do not know what else to do, help me!

Comment: Any time you concat an object with a string, this is the result you get. Stop concatenating an object with a string and your problem will go away.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is the object values are objects. In the [link you provided](https://vimeo.com/api/oembed.json?url=http://vimeo.com/13211055), all the object values are strings, or integers, so your code would work correctly:

```
{
    type: "video",
    version: "1.0",
    ...
}
```

Here, you can see how it will work. When you try to convert an object to a string, it will show as `[object object]`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var result = {test: "testing", test2: {obj: 'test'}};
  $.each(result, function(i, field){
    $("p").append(field + " ");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

You either need to recursively loop through each field (shown below), or only display what you want:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var result = {test: "testing", test2: {obj: 'test'}};
  
  var appendObj = function(obj) {
    $.each(obj, function(i, field){
      if ($.isPlainObject(field)) {
        //We're dealing with another object, loop through it, and echo it's contents
        appendObj(field);
      } else {
        //Just a regular field, append like normal.
        $("p").append(field + " ");
      }
    });
  };
  
  //Start the appending with the main result.
  appendObj(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.
I took all the fields that continue numbers, my json return by the browser is like this:

[
{
"PES_PESSOA": "F",
"PES_NAME": "ELLEM CRISTINA F",
"PES_FANTASIA": "ELLEM CRISTINA F"
}
]

but by jquery it's still the same, sorry, but I'm still learning.

Comment: @EllemCristina My second code snippet displays data for the string you provided.

Comment: It worked, the problem was on the server, who was coming back exactly what he told me, thank you!